# Flask-SQLAlchemy import/context issue

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to structure my Flask app something like:

```
./site.py
./apps/members/__init__.py
./apps/members/models.py
```

`apps.members` is a Flask Blueprint.

Now, in order to create the model classes I need to have a hold of the app, something like:

```
# apps.members.models
from flask import current_app
from flaskext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(current_app)

class Member(db.Model):
    # fields here
    pass
```

But if I try and import that model into my Blueprint app, I get the dreaded `RuntimeError: working outside of request context`. How can I get a hold of my app correctly here? Relative imports might work but they're pretty ugly and have their own context issues, e.g:

```
from ...site import app

# ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Answer (score 401, accepted):

The `flask_sqlalchemy` module does not have to be initialized with the app right away - you can do this instead:

```
# apps.members.models
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Member(db.Model):
    # fields here
    pass
```

And then in your application setup you can call `init_app`:

```
# apps.application.py
from flask import Flask
from apps.members.models import db

app = Flask(__name__)
# later on
db.init_app(app)
```

This way you can avoid cyclical imports.

This pattern does *not* necessitate the you place all of your models in one file.  Simply import the `db` variable into each of your model modules.

#### Example

```
# apps.shared.models
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

```
# apps.members.models
from apps.shared.models import db

class Member(db.Model):
    # TODO: Implement this.
    pass
```

```
# apps.reporting.members
from flask import render_template
from apps.members.models import Member

def report_on_members():
    # TODO: Actually use arguments
    members = Member.filter(1==1).all()
    return render_template("report.html", members=members)
```

```
# apps.reporting.routes
from flask import Blueprint
from apps.reporting.members import report_on_members

reporting = Blueprint("reporting", __name__)

reporting.route("/member-report", methods=["GET","POST"])(report_on_members)
```

```
# apps.application
from flask import Flask
from apps.shared import db
from apps.reporting.routes import reporting

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(reporting)
```

<sub>**Note:** this is a *sketch* of some of the power this gives you - there is obviously quite a bit more that you can do to make development even easier (using a `create_app` pattern, auto-registering blueprints in certain folders, etc.)</sub>

Comment: Can you do that multiple times? For example if I have more than one models.py file?

Comment: @BradWright - it makes it easier if you create only `db` instance for each database that you have.  If you have a package of models you can put it in `__init__.py`.  However you choose to do it, you simply import the `db` variable from that location into your other model files and use it as normal.  When they are loaded everything resolves correctly.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to a project that is set up this way?

Comment: @Mbrevda - you can see an example of this pattern here https://github.com/svieira/Budget-Manager

Comment: is the `.ext` namespace still necessary, or should we just import from `flask_sqlalchemy` these days?

Comment: The `.ext.` namespace is deprecated - it's better to import from the real namespace (`flask_sqlalchemy`).

Comment: This is a great answer and should be included in the official flask-sqlalchemy documentation as I was looking for this for quite a while.

Comment: I don't know what it's lacking, but this whole example creates the database, but the table for the model...

Comment: Can we also do CustomBase with this one?

Comment: what if a model need to be imported in another model file?

Comment: There's no harm to that.  `DB` gets imported into `ModelA` and `DB + ModelA` get imported into `ModelB` - there's no circular import issues.

Comment: Hi, you have a comment on top of your files eg.  # apps.application . How does it help? This is new to me and i would love to learn if it does something extra.

Comment: Hi @Max08 - the comment is just to show you the name of the module the code snippet represents.  This makes it easier for people to follow along here on StackOverflow, it doesn't have any meaning to Python and you don't need it in your real application.

Answer (score 31):

an original **app.py**: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

```
...

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...

class Computer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...

# Create the database tables.
db.create_all()

...

# start the flask loop
app.run()
```

I just splitted one app.py to app.py and model.py without using Blueprint. In that case, the above answer dosen't work. A line code is needed to work.

**before**:

```
db.init_app(app)
```

**after**:

```
db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
```

And, the following link is very useful.

http://piotr.banaszkiewicz.org/blog/2012/06/29/flask-sqlalchemy-init_app/

Comment: `db.app = app` was getting runtimeerror because init_app doesnt set app. +1

Comment: `db.app = app` (followed by `db.init_app(app)`) was the missing piece for me. Works perfectly after adding that line (combined with Sean Vieira' answer)

Comment: First link is outdated.

Comment: adding `db.app = app` worked straight away.. this should be added to official docs.