# When scattering Flask Models, RuntimeError: 'application not registered on db' was raised

Tags: python, flask

I am re-factoring my Flask application by scattering the models, blueprints but I am having a runtime error.

```
def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask("app")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()
    return app
```

I have the following problem(the sample project are hosted here: https://github.com/chfw/sample):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 17, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "application.py", line 12, in create_app
    db.create_all()
  File "\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 856, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 836, in _execute_for_all_tables
    app = self.get_app(app)
  File "\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 809, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db 
           'RuntimeError: application not registered on db 
            instance and no application bound to current context
```

I did a research on this topic. The re-factoring is suggested here:

[Flask-SQLAlchemy import/context issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue)

The same problem was raised here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2010/8/30/sqlalchemy-init-app-problem/#b1c3beb68573efef4d6e571ebc68fa0b

And the above thread(2010) suggested a hack like this:

```
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    db.app=app #<------------<<
    db.init_app(app)
```

Did anyone know how to do this properly? How did you solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This has to do with Flask's [application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/). When initialized with `db.init_app(app)`, Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't know which app is the "current" app (remember, Flask allows for [multiple apps](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/) in the same interpreter). You could have multiple apps using the same `SQLAlchemy` instance in the same process, and Flask-SQLAlchemy would need to know which is the "current" one (due to Flask's [context local](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#context-locals) nature of everything).

If you need to do this during runtime, you must explicitly say which app is the "current" app for all calls. You can do this by changing your code to use a `with app.app_context()` block:

```
def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask("app")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
    app.register_blueprint(api)
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        # Extensions like Flask-SQLAlchemy now know what the "current" app
        # is while within this block. Therefore, you can now run........
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

---

If you are writing a standalone script that needs the app context, you can push the context at the beginning rather than putting everything in a `with` block.

```
create_app().app_context().push()
```

If you write a command for Flask's [cli](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/cli/#custom-commands) the command will automatically have access to the context.

Comment: Right, this works. Now I don't get the exceptions. But next one is: "application not registered on db" -> RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context

Comment: Whats the difference here and adding db.app = app ?

Comment: @user805981 That way might work, but it's not very clean. First, you're breaking encapsulation, since the `app` attribute on the SQLAlchemy is not designed to be public. That object might need to do other things when it is changing what app it is using. Second, `app_context` does more than just change Flask-SQLAlchemy; it actually tells Flask to change the current app. Thus, you might need this to do things with various Flask APIs, or work with the app with all of your other Flask extensions.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I'm having a similar problem with a celery's periodic task not knowing the context. Even with your update. My only workaround was to do db.app=app. Is there something wrong with my periodic app causing it to not know where the app_context is? My question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706020/how-to-access-the-orm-with-celery-tasks Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Mark's answer was great and it helped me a lot.  However, another way to approach this is to run the code that relies on the app context in a function decorated with @app.before_first_request.  See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/ for more information.  That's in fact how I ended up doing it, largely because I wanted to be able to call the initialization code outside of flask as well, which I handle this way.

In my case I want to be able to test SQLAlchemy models as plain SQLAlchemy models without Flask-SQLAlchemy, though the db in the code below is simply a (Flask) SQLAlchemy db.

```
@app.before_first_request
def recreate_test_databases(engine = None, session = None):
  if engine == None:
    engine = db.engine
  if session == None:
    session = db.session

  Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
  Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
  # Additional setup code
```

Comment: John, could you merge the duplicate answer into this one (since this one has upvotes) and delete the other?

Comment: Deleted, no merge needed.

Comment: Any suggestion for a file that should hold `@app.before_first_request` functions?