# Initialize a Flask-WhooshAlchemy index when using the app factory pattern

Tags: python, flask

I am developing an app with Flask using the [application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions). Initializing the Whoosh index doesn't work, because `current_app` cannot be used without setting up an app context explicitly. How do I do this?

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from .frontend import frontend

def create_app(configfile=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    from .models import db
    db.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(frontend)

    return app
```

`models.py`

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask_whooshalchemy as wa
from flask import current_app

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Institution(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['name', 'description']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

# this does not work
wa.whoosh_index(current_app, Institution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can't use `current_app` outside an application context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437883/when-scattering-flask-models-runtimeerror-application-not-registered-on-db-w)  An application context exists during a request, or when explicitly created with `app.app_context()`.

Import your models during `create_app` and index them with Whoosh there.  Remember, the factory is where you're performing all setup for the application.

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask('myapp')
    ...
    from myapp.models import Institution
    wa.whoosh_index(app, Institution)
    ...
    return app
```

If you want to keep the code local to the blueprint, you can use the blueprint's `record_once` function to perform the index when the blueprint is registered on the app.

```
@bp.record_once
def record_once(state):
    wa.whoosh_index(state.app, Institution)
```

This will be called at most once when registering the blueprint with an app.  `state` contains the app, so you don't need the `current_app`.