# python module import conundrum (module from submodule)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have the following project structure:

```
./app/__init__.py
./app/main/__init__.py
./app/main/views.py
./app/models.py
./app/resources/__init__.py
./app/resources/changesAPI.py
./config.py
./manage.py
```

The `app/models.py` file has the following line:

```
from app import db
```

`db` is defined in `app/__init__.py`

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

I'm importing classes from models.py from `app/resources/__init__.py`:

```
from app.models import User, Task, TaskChange, Revision
```

However, it fails when model tries to import `db`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import create_app, db, api
  File "/Users/nahuel/proj/ptcp/app/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from app.resources.changesAPI import ChangesAPI
  File "/Users/nahuel/proj/ptcp/app/resources/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app.models import User, Task, TaskChange, Revision
  File "/Users/nahuel/proj/ptcp/app/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
ImportError: cannot import name db
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue for some discussion on alternate ways to do things :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import.

You are importing `create_app`, `db` and `api` from `manage.py`, which triggers an import of the `app.resources.changesAPI` module, which in turn then triggers import of the `__init__.py` package in `app/resources` which then tries to import your `models`, which fails because `db` was not yet defined in `app/__init__.py`.

You need to move importing `ChangesAPI` to *after* the line that defines `db` in your `app/__init__.py` file. Any name defined in `app/__init__.py` before the `from app.resources.changesAPI import ChangesAPI` is available to your sub-packages, names after are not.