# with Flask-sqlalchemy, connect models to database without running app

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I used the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue) question to fix a circular import when setting up Flask-SQLAlchemy.  The solution works because you don't have to import the `app` from the `application.py` file to get the database URI - it initalizes the connection just before running the app.  The issue now is that I typically like import my `models` file into a python interpreter just so I can test the models (and the connection to the database) without actually running the app.  But with this setup, just importing `models` won't establish a connection to PostGres.

Is there a way to establish a connection to PostGres through `Flask-SQLAlchemy` without actually initializing and running an app?  Maybe I can provide `db` with the URI to my database directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study this code 
https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt
there is a link on github explaining the design. What should be your main focus is the usage of flask-script. I think you have to use the factory pattern, but you want to do that anyway if you are doing anything remotly serious.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching for this one [github.com/mardix/active-alchemy](https://github.com/mardix/active-alchemy)

> Active-Alchemy is a framework agnostic wrapper for SQLAlchemy that makes it really easy to use by implementing a simple active record like api, while it still uses the db.session underneath. Inspired by Flask-SQLAlchemy

Comment: You can't really mix it with Flask-SQLAlchemy. It adds these records 'created_at', 'deleted_at' which will clash. I'm realizing you have to replace Flask-SQLAlchemy with Active-Alchemy entirely which I wasn't really expecting.