# Flask-Security - Application Context Issue - Peewee

Tags: python, flask, flask-security, flask-peewee

I am working on expanding my flask skills and have worked on the treehouse flask social network project and got it to work. I am now playing with changing settings and allowing social login I have moved over to flask-security from plain bcrypt as it is a requirement of flask-social. I have separate app and models files and I am running into `RuntimeError: working outside of application context` when I try to use the `utils.encrypt_password()` function it throws the error. I can get it to remove the error by doing `from app import app` then it states that my database is not an attribute of the module.

I am totally confused I have googled the issue but keep getting errors with peoples suggestions wondering if someone could explain what I am doing wrong. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue) to a question i think might be similar but I don't understand in terms of my code. I have posted my code below to show you my user model and the top half of my app.py as these are the two parts that are in the stacktraces.

**Models.py**

```
import datetime
#from app import app
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin
from flask.ext.security import Security, RoleMixin, utils
from peewee import *

DATABASE = SqliteDatabase('social.db')
#DATABASE = SqliteDatabase(None)

class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=100)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-joined_at',)

    def get_posts(self):
        return Post.select().where(Post.user == self)

    def get_stream(self):
        return Post.select().where(
            (Post.user << self.following()) |
            (Post.user == self))

    def following(self):
        return (
            User.select().join(
                    Relationship, on=Relationship.to_user
            ).where(
                Relationship.from_user == self
            )
        )

    def followers(self):
        return (
            User.select().join(
                Relationship, on=Relationship.from_user
            ).where(
                Relationship.to_user == self
            )
        )

    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, admin=False):
        try:
            with DATABASE.transaction():
                cls.create(
                    username=username,
                    email=email,
                    password=utils.encrypt_password(password),
                    is_admin=admin)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("User already exists")

def initialise():
    #DATABASE.init_app(app)
    DATABASE.connect()
    DATABASE.create_tables([User, Post, Relationship, Role, UserRoles, Connection], safe=True)
    DATABASE.close()
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import (Flask, g, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, abort, session, request )
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
from flask.ext.social import Social, PeeweeConnectionDatastore
from flask.ext.security import PeeweeUserDatastore, Security
from flask.ext.social.utils import get_provider_or_404
from flask.ext.social.views import connect_handler
from peewee import *

import forms
import models

DEBUG = True
PORT = 8000
HOST = '0.0.0.0'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'tfdghsf3wquhivfcdsz5.5432jkicdsahuihuj7564jinjnf'

app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH'] = 'pbkdf2_sha512'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = '1b3kxc8s9fdsa9431vbgvhui43212ijkdrdwui'

app.config['SOCIAL_GOOGLE'] = {
    'consumer_key': '1048991051512-6k0vianfkdece33tool0el7pg72h5lku.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'consumer_secret': 'kDyeeetXqIEq7G9LfGfozLH9'
}
DATABASE = SqliteDatabase('social.db')
app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN'] = '/profile'
user_datastore = PeeweeUserDatastore(models.DATABASE, models.User, models.Role, models.UserRoles)
social_datastore = PeeweeConnectionDatastore(models.DATABASE, models.Connection)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)
social = Social(app, social_datastore)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
```

**EDIT:**
After looking further into the issue it seems like it might be an issue with flask-security as I implemented a test function in my main app.py and that two gave the same runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question actually lies in the location of my user creation. I had left it where it was in the main section where my program runs code bellow shows this and it looks like it was out of context I moved my default user creation to a function with the `@app.before_first_request` decorator and it now works.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
            models.User.create_user(
                username='BenBrown',
                email='ben@aperturedigital.uk',
                password='password',
                admin=True
            )
    except ValueError:
        pass

    app.run(debug=DEBUG, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```