# I cannot create tables using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Following this [tutorial](https://stackabuse.com/using-sqlalchemy-with-flask-and-postgresql/) of using SQLAlchemy and Postgresql, I based myself for creating a file structure of models, views, templates etc..

```
requirements.txt
run.py
website/
    __init__.py
    views/
    models/
          users.py
    static/
    templates/
```

As you can see, inside models I have users.py

```
from app import db

class Users(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self.user = user
        self.password= password


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.user}>"
```

My init.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/project"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


#Routes
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Now, I used these commands to create user table `flask db init`, `flask db migrate`, `flask db upgrade`. OK, after this, was created a table named `public.alembic_version`, but as you see, Users didnt.

My last tried, was insert this import `from models import users` between:

```
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from models import users

    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
```

But the message is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'` I thought that I'm using a reserved word, even changing folder, page name, the error keeps, just change module name.

Update:

**Final result, this example work to me**

run.py

```
from website import app
from website.models.users import User

app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True,port=5000)
```

### Update

```
requirements.txt
run.py
website/
    __init__.py
    views/
    models.py
    static/
    templates/
```

What I changed is remove Models Folder e create a file models.py and adding the class Users, Purchase, anything that I want...

I took these imports and include in top of my `models.py`...

```
from website import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import psycopg2
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres://postgres:password@ipaddress:5432/databasename"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

In `__init__.py` added in end of line, after blueprints imports, if I wanted do it, `from website.models import Users`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

from website.models import Usuario
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can find is that you add an import statement (`from models import users`) in your last attached part of the code. However, you have not created an `__init__.py` inside your `models` folder, to declare it as a module. So, that you can import it later as a module like you have created an `__init__.py` file in your main directory ("website/"). But how you import the `models.py` file in your `run.py` file? In your `run.py` file you should import the models like `from website.models.users import Users`.

I have two working projects, where I also use **FlaskSQLAlchemy** & **PostgreSQL**, but I have set as the `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://postgres:[password]@localhost:5432/[database_name]'`. It works perfectly fine by putting `postgres` instead of `postgresql` for the engine configuration.

Reference: [Flask-SQLAlchemy import/context issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692962/flask-sqlalchemy-import-context-issue/9695045#9695045)

---

**UPDATE**

Well, you have put your business login (routes, ...) in the `init.py` file. If you want it to run, I think you should probably put it in the `run.py` file. Leave the `__init__.py` files empty.

Furthermore, in your `app.py` file import your models like this: `from .website.models import Users`. This requires that you have three `__init__.py` files. One in your main directory where `app.py` is located, one in the `website` folder, and one in the `models` folder.

*I hope that helps. Please let me know if this works, and if there is anything else I can help you with.

Comment: Thank you for answering @georgekrax. I have just created a `__init__.py` inside `Models` folder, even so, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`.  About DATBASE_URI, I changed as you suggested

Comment: Let me see if I got it! I'm importing `models` in my `run.py` as `website.models.users import Users`, or inside `__init__`, I Got a message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` about `from app import db`, inside models users

Comment: You import it in `run.py`, YES. I edited again, go check it out!

Comment: What do you think? Did it, I receive the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` from users models.

Comment: Yes, but I noticed also that you have your code (routes) in the `init.py` file. In the `__init__.py` file we put extra information and declare modules, and not our code's logic (views).

Comment: I have habit to write just index page route in __init__ rather than create a view only for this. For example, anothers logics, like users I'd have a views/user and templates/users (index, add, view ,..,etc).

Comment: Ok, but do not put the code in the `__init__.py` file. It is different if it is named only `init.py` though, without the underscores. It is not the place for this part of your code. Hope that helps

Comment: Should I change `__init__.py` to `app.py`, all I did, didn't work

Comment: No just add your code (routes) from the `__init__.py` file to a newly created file. You can name the new file `app.py`.

Comment: Thanks @georgekrax, with your advices I got it to make this work!

Comment: @TMoraes, I am so pleased and happy to hear that you got this to work! Thank you so much, and I appreciate your help, by giving me the corresponding reputation. Please contact me if you want help with anything else in the future.